# using "Large if" in vba

Tags: excel, if-statement, vba

I am working on a spreadsheet in which I have data of quarter-wise sales by co. and sector. My data is arranged in below mentioned format:

Row 1 has date
Data starts from row 2
**Column B:** Company Name
**Column C:** Sector Name of the co. for ex. energy, materials, technology etc
**Column D:** Sales figure of co.
**Column E, F, G:** Price, shares, volume of co.
**Column H:** Blank
From next column onwards I have same data fields for next quarter
**Column I:** Company Name
**Column J:** Sector Name of the co. for ex. energy, materials, technology etc
**Column K:** Sales figure of co
So on and so forth

Now, in another worksheet I need to get name and sales figures for top 3/5/10/15 etc (top n co.s depending on user input) within each sector. For ex. sales figures and co. name of top 3 companies in Energy sector.
I have been trying to write a vba code for this but I am struggling. I have mentioned below the code I was trying but its not flexible at all since in my code I have given reference of column C and D which would actually change after each quarter

```
Sub try()

Dim r As Long
n = Range("topcos").Value + 5

For r = 5 To n
    p = 1
    Worksheets("Top co. share with co name").Activate
    Cells(r, 16).Select
    Selection.FormulaArray = "=LARGE(IF('Co Wise'!$C$3:$C$600=P$3,'Co Wise'!$D$3:$D$600,""""),p)"
    p = p + 1
Next r

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Nicolas, I am not able to view your answer.

Comment: I am wondering what this has to do with VBA programming. Is it because you are using VBA to enter a formula into a cell? Why don't you enter the formula manually and you're done?

Comment: I can enter the formula manually but the no. of top values are needed are not fixed. So it can be top 3 / 5 / 10 or any. that is why I want to write in VBA so that depending on no. of top values needed, accordingly the rows are inserted.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you merely forgot that p is a variable and should be treated as such in the formula:

```
Selection.FormulaArray = "=LARGE(IF('Co Wise'!$C$3:$C$600=P$3,'Co Wise'!$D$3:$D$600,"""")," & p & ")"
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively:

```
Sub SO()

Sheets("Top co. share with co name").Range("P5:P" & [topcos] + 5).FormulaArray = _
"=LARGE(IF('Co Wise'!$C$3:$C$600=P$3,'Co Wise'!$D$3:$D$600,""""),ROW()-4)"

End Sub
```

Would do the same thing without the need for loops and variables.